# How can I stop ASP.net from marking .dll's read only then throwing errors on rebuild?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, tfs, asp.net-core

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928200/how-can-i-stop-asp-net-from-blocking-access-to-files-then-throwing-access-denied) but would like to narrow it down since I've figured workarounds for all but two .dll files in the bin folder.

> **Problem:**
>
> Every time I rebuild or debug, the project throws an error because
>   those two dll's are read only.
>
> In file explorer I go to that folder and remove the read only flag and
>   all is well UNTIL the next time I rebuild. They're set to read only
>   again. I've been going in and un-checking read only every freaking
>   time I rebuild and it's become a real pain.

Please tell me there's a way around this.

I'm using .net Core RC2 with VS Pro 2015 Update 3 RC (version 14.0.25402.00)

I have a class library in my project with references to these two dll's (they are not referenced directly in my project)

and a reference to that class library in my solution's /src/(proj_name)/References/.NET Framework 4.6.1 directory.

And, those two dll's from the class library are replicated in my project's /bin/Debug/net461/win7-x64 directory

The project is checked into TFS, which I suspect is why the files are being marked read only HOWEVER, they do not show up in Source Control Explorer (they shouldn't, right? It's a dll in the bin) and I'm wondering if they're in there anyway but hidden, since the folder is hidden in my project by default.

Comment: what is the output set to for those .dll's when you reference them..? why not create a dependency folder, remove the reference to the .dll, make the changes to the .dll one time once you have placed it in the dependency folder, then read add the reference this time pointing to the new dependency folder that you have created. also make sure that the Copy Local = is set to true..

Comment: Which kind of build are you using ? Vnext or Xaml? And Dll in TFS will not shown in the Source Control Explorer . It's a right phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be solved! A bit counter-intuitive but I checked the dll files out of source control (right click > "Check Out for Edit") from the project my project was referencing, which also unlocked the dll's being referenced behind the scenes in my main project. Smooth building so far!